# How to get ARFCN in Android 6.0( Marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

How can I use below implementation in **Android 6.0** framework.

```
gsm.getCellIdentity().getArfcn();
```

I know above implementation is added in **Android 7.0**, but I am interested in adding this patch to **6.0**.

For your Information: I don't want to upgrade **Android to 7.0**.

Thanks 
Mohan

Comment: Hi ,Can I get any answer to my question please?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?